# Do I Have to Use fetch_assoc() when getting MAX in a table in MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to get ONLY the MAX value in a column in Table , Do I need to use `fetch_assoc();` here too? (for getting a single value)?

```
$query1  = "SELECT MAX(`cost`) AS MaxNum FROM `ccotTbl`";
$result  = $conn->query($query1);
$nums1   = $result->fetch_assoc(); 
$maxNum  = $nums1['MaxNum'];
$_maxNum = $maxNum;
```

Thanks

Comment: Your Common Sense, this is totally different question! I am not asking how to do this? I am using OOP style and I need to know even if I am getting single value back I still need to use the fetch_assoc()? PLEASE do not just mark questions as duplicated!

Comment: So you want to know if you can get results without fetching it? No, you can't. You also can't read a book without getting it into your hands.